# How to fix the replay function in this code?

Tags: java

I am coding this to ask the player to guess a random number. After they finish the guessing or get the correct answer, the program will end. This part works ok for now. However, the second part, when they finish the first round, I want the program to ask the user if they want to replay. But the function for "I want to replay" is not working here. Can anyone help how to modify this?

```
public static void main( String [] args )
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); //create scanner object

    int maxNumber = 0; //initial value for MaxNumber
    int userGuess = 0; //initial value for UserGuess
    int totalGuesses = 0; //initial value for TotalGuesses
    int randomNumber = 0; //initial value for RandomNumber
    int maxAttempts = 0; //initial value for MaxAttempts
    int end = 0;
    int replay = 0;

    do
    {        

            System.out.println( "Please enter a maximum value: " ); //Ask user to input a max number
            maxNumber = scan.nextInt(); //set MaxNumber to user input

            System.out.println( "Please enter a maximum attempts: " ); //Ask user to input max attempts
            maxAttempts = scan.nextInt(); //set Attempts to user input

            randomNumber = (int) ( maxNumber * Math.random() ) + 1; //generate a secret number
            System.out.println( "A new secret number has been generated" 
                + "\n Input your guess" ); //ask user to input a guess

        while (totalGuesses < maxAttempts)
        {
            userGuess = scan.nextInt(); //set UserGuess to user input 
    totalGuesses++; //increment total number of guesses by 1

            if (userGuess < randomNumber) //while user's guess is less than the secret number
            {
                System.out.println("Sorry, that is too low! Please try again.");  
            }

            else if (userGuess > randomNumber) //while user's guess is greater than the secret number
            {
                System.out.println("Sorry, that is too high! Please try again."); 
            }

            else if (userGuess == randomNumber) //if user guesses correctly
            {
                System.out.println(" Your guess is correct!" // let user know the guess is correct
                        + "\n Total number of guesses: " + totalGuesses); // display total number of guesses
            }

           while (userGuess == randomNumber | totalGuesses == maxAttempts)
           {
                System.out.println("Would you like to play again? Please input 1 for Yes or 2 for no and press enter."); 
                //ask user if they would like to play again
                replay = scan.nextInt();
                if (replay == 1);
                {
                 end == 0;
                }

                if (replay == 2); 
                {
                 end == 1;
                 System.out.print("Thanks for playing!");
                }
           }
        } 
    }while (end == 0);

}
```

I expect when user put 1, they can replay. And the program should stop when they enter 2.

Comment: Where you check the replay value, you are not _assigning_ a value to end, you have `==`.

Comment: You need to re-work your logic. `end == 0;` should be `end = 0;` and `if` conditions should not end with a semi-colon. Also, `userGuess`,`randomNumber`,`totalGuesses` and `maxAttempts` never change inside the while loop, so it effectively becomes an infinte loop.